# Beam streaming pipeline does not write files to bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

UI have a python streaming pipeline on GCP Dataflow that reads thousands of messages from a PubSub, like this:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
      lines = p | "read" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=str(job_options.inputTopic))
      lines = lines | "decode" >> beam.Map(decode_message)
      lines = lines | "Parse" >> beam.Map(parse_json)
      lines = lines | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(1*60))
      lines = lines | "Add device id key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (elem.get('id'), elem))
      lines = lines | "Group by key" >> beam.GroupByKey()
      lines = lines | "Abandon key" >> beam.Map(flatten)
      lines | "WriteToAvro" >> beam.io.WriteToAvro(job_options.outputLocation, schema=schema, file_name_suffix='.avro', mime_type='application/x-avro')
```

The pipeline runs just fine, except it never produces any output. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi @gixen, looking at the error it seems as though your beam.Map is returning a PCollection where each element is a list. Can you please edit your post with the code of your flatten function?

Comment: thanks. Basically I want to remove the key added in the 'Add device id key.

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of the above errors by debugging in more detail. Turned out that some records were null/None from the source, and some records were translated to dict, not json. Those are now fixed.

The remaining issue seems to be that the WriteToAvro never writes to the bucket. Is it not supposed to do that until the job is done?

Comment: It looks like you have some values that are contradicting the schema by trying to write a float to an int type. It looks like the Beam WriteToAvro doesn't support unbounded PCollections like what you have. I'm writing a response that has a work-around.

Comment: It might be best if you were to reframe your question as why the WriteToAvro transform doesn't work as this best generalizes the questions for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there were a few problems with your code. First,  there was some badly formatted data with regards to null/None (you fixed already) and ints/floats (called out in comments). Finally, the [WriteToAvro](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9c3941fcc6f09ce517223350f8505b2981907743/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/avroio.py#L494) transform cannot write unbounded PCollections. There is a work-around in which you define a new [sink](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d76596c0753950c024a035465413e747ec3be2a3/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L259) and use that with the [WriteToFiles](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d76596c0753950c024a035465413e747ec3be2a3/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L401) transform which is able to write unbounded PCollections.

Note that as of the writing of this post (2020-06-18), this method does not work with the Apache Beam Python SDK <= 2.23. This is because the Python pickler cannot deserialize a pickled Avro schema (see [BEAM-6522](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6522)). In this case, this forces a solution to use FastAvro instead. You can use Avro if you manually upgrade dill 
 to >= 0.3.1.1 **and** Avro to >= 1.9.0, but be careful as this is currently untested.

With the caveats out of the way, here is the work-around:

```
from apache_beam.io.fileio import FileSink
from apache_beam.io.fileio import WriteToFiles
import fastavro

class AvroFileSink(FileSink):
    def __init__(self, schema, codec='deflate'):
        self._schema = schema
        self._codec = codec

    def open(self, fh):
        # This is called on every new bundle.
        self.writer = fastavro.write.Writer(fh, self._schema, self._codec)

    def write(self, record):
        # This is called on every element.
        self.writer.write(record)

    def flush(self):
        self.writer.flush()
```

This new sink is used like the following:

```
import apache_beam as beam

# Replace the following with your schema.
schema = fastavro.schema.parse_schema({
    'name': 'row',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [
        {'name': 'a', 'type': 'int'},
    ],
})

# Create the sink. This will be used by the WriteToFiles transform to write
# individual elements to the Avro file.
sink = AvroFileSink(schema=schema)

with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
    lines = p | beam.ReadFromPubSub(...)
    lines = ...

    # This is where your new sink gets used. The WriteToFiles transform takes
    # the sink and uses it to write to a directory defined by the path 
    # argument.
    lines | WriteToFiles(path=job_options.outputLocation, sink=sink)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. We've decide moving over to Java for now.